# Best/Worst Test Cases

Tags: analysis, algorithms

For the two functions, would their worst/best Big O cases change compared to each others? If so, how would they change. I believe that when dealing with Big O, order is the only thing that matters, so would that not mean that even while their individual best/worst cases can change, would it not be in the same order in Big O?

```
def swapSort(L): 
    """ L is a list on integers """
    print "Original L: ", L
    for i in range(len(L)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(L)):
            if L[j] < L[i]:
                # the next line is a short 
                # form for swap L[i] and L[j]
                L[j], L[i] = L[i], L[j] 
                print L
    print "Final L: ", L
```

and

```
def modSwapSort(L): 
    """ L is a list on integers """
    print "Original L: ", L
    for i in range(len(L)):
        for j in range(len(L)):
            if L[j] < L[i]:
                # the next line is a short 
                # form for swap L[i] and L[j]
                L[j], L[i] = L[i], L[j] 
                print L
    print "Final L: ", L
```

Comment: Simultaneously cross-posted on CS.SE: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/28681/755

Comment: Crossposting is considered rude and invites duplication of effort. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference between the two routines is that the second has some extra steps. The second could be written as

```
...
[1] for i in range(len(L)):
[2]   for j in range(1, i):
[3]      if L[j] < L[i]:
[4]         #swap
[5]   for j in range(i+1, len(l)):
[6]      if L[j] < L[i]:
[7]         #swap
```

So the second version differs from the first by the statements in the loop [2]...[4]. The important thing to note is that the first and the second versions will both have the loop invariant that after the outer loop iterates the $i$-th time, $L[i]\le L[j]$ for all $j>i$. In other words, the initial segment $L[1],\dots, L[i]$ will be in their proper locations in sorted order. This means that the body of the **if** statement at [3] will never be executed so all you've added to the run time is the loop overhead and the **if** test. It's easy to see that this (quadratic) contribution will be no larger than the quadratic run time of the rest of the first routine, so the asymptotic run times of the two loops will be the same.

The worst case scenario (the big-O estimate) for both will be when the list is initially sorted in reverse order. In that case the first routine will require $(n-1) + (n-2) + \dots 1=O(n^2)$ swaps and the second will take that many swaps plus no others, for the same asymptotic run time.

The best case scenario (the big-omega estimate) will be when the list is initially sorted, in which case both will do no swaps.

Finally, if yu look at the rest of the contributions to the run times, namely the loop overheads and the **if** tests, the first will take $O(n-1)+O(n-2)+\dots +O(1)=O(n^2)$ steps and the second will take $O(n)+O(n)+\dots+ O(n)=O(n^2)$ steps. In summary, in this pair of examples, the asymptotic running times, both upper and lower, will be the same.